# Split given string using java regex and not normal string.split method

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string like

```
ABC : blablabla,DEF : blablabla,GEH : blablabla etc...
```

I want to split above string to capture only the 3 letter words using a comma and finally save value to DB
Sometimes there might be null value completely or even single `key:value` pair without any comma's.

Does anyone has any idea..?

Comment: `split` on comma, iterate over result array, check if element has proper format (non empty and so on), substring only first 3 characters, save them to DB.

Comment: Cant you use [Java String Split function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split the string with `,` delimiter and then Iterate over the individual String, split them by `:` if they have proper format and save in your db, if not in proper format, insert NULLs as placeholders

Comment: thanks Pshemo, but I dont want to use split method rather want to use regex.

Comment: split IS using regex, but I guess you want a Matcher?

Comment: want to know the pattern for regex to do this?

Comment: Such pattern is not that hard to create. You probably attempt to do it so can you describe problem you are having with it?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add more details about problem you are facing.

Comment: Do some reading on pattern matching regular expressions. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it's done with a `Matcher`, it's so short that I will give it away, but you should describe your approach first and why it is not working.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:[^a-zA-Z]+|^)([a-zA-Z]{3}) *:");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(...);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: thanks maraca, am not really very strong with regex but wanted to use it, so asked it.

Comment: yw, what it's basically doing is: see if it's at the beginning or non-letters are there (non capturing group) followed by the 3 letters, followed by any amount of spaces and a colon, it allows to match abc:b cde:d fgh:e if the comma is ommitted or other delimiters are used.